# Probability every hyperplane contains at most $m/2$ vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I pick $m \geq n$ vectors drawn uniformly from  $\{-1,1\}^n$, and call the set of vectors  $X$.  What is the probability that for every non-zero $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exist at least $m/2$ vectors in $X$ which are not orthogonal to $v$?

If an exact probability is not possible, can bounds be found?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Is the characterization equivalent to the probability that all vectors in the image of a randomly chosen $y\times x$-matrix with entries in $\{-1,+1\}$ has at least $y/2$ entries that are non-zero?

Comment: I modified a little (for better, I hope) the question. One doubt remains: isn't the restriction $|v|=1$ irrelevant?

Comment: @benh I think that is right.

Comment: If I get it right, the answer is zero for $m=n$, because the system $X v =z$ has a solution for $z=(1,0,0 \cdots 0)$ if X is full range (if it's not, then it's even simpler). I think this can be extended.

Comment: @leonbloy Isn't the prob non-zero for n=m=2? Consider the vectors (1,1) and (1,-1). If v is orthogonal to one of them it is not orthogonal to the other.

Comment: @marshall Yes, you're right, I missed that case. The answer is zero for $m=n >2$

Comment: In fact we need $\lfloor m/2 \rfloor +1 \geq n$ by considering the rank of the aforementioned matrix. However, there seems to be more: I wrote a little program to enumerate all matrices that suffice the condition, which produced the following: for $n=2$ the number of matrices (and hence the probability) is $0$ for $m$ odd and $$\frac{4^n(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$ else. For $n=3$ I only found solutions for $m=8,12$ if $m<14$.

Comment: @benh Can you explain what your code does? It can't try all real vectors.

Comment: The probability of this event is very small. My guess would be that it is at most $O((1/\sqrt{2\pi m})^{n(n-1)/2})$. It is possible to compute it exactly for small values of $n$. For $n=2$, it is equal to $\binom{2m}{m}/2^m$ if $m$ is even, and $0$ if $m$ is odd. For $n=3$, it is equal to $\frac{(4m)!}{4^m (m!)^4}$ if $m$ is divisible by 4, and 0 otherwise. Also, the function is a decreasing function as a function of $n$.

Comment: There is a typo in my comment. For $n=3$, it should be $m!/(4^{m} ((m/4)!)^4)$ (if $m$ is divisible by 4).

Comment: For $n=2$, it should be $\binom{m}{m/2} / 2^m$ if $m$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: @Yury This is very interesting and I would love to understand this more (I hope you will be able to add an answer).  One question, if $m=n^2$, say, are you still saying that the probability is a decreasing function of $n$?

Comment: Let $p(m,n)$ be the desired probability. Then for every $m$ and $n$, $p(m,n+1) < p(m,n)$ unless $p(m,n) =0$; if $p(m,n) =0$ then $p(m,n+1) = p(m,n) = 0$.

Comment: @marshall You can check for all $m \times n$ matrices with entries in $-1$, $1$ if every submatrix obtained by deleting $\lceil m/2\rceil -1$ of the $m$ rows is of full rank. This is equivalent to the problem statement. I can reproduce the results of Yuri (in the formula I posted above I mean $m$ rather then $n$, as $n=2$ is fixed). The code can be optimized significantly by considering various symmetries the problem has.

Comment: @benh Very interesting. What do you get if you try $m/3$ instead of $m/2$ out of interest?

Comment: @marshall I am sorry, again I confused terms: you choose $\lfloor m/2 \rfloor+1$ instead of $\lceil m/2 \rceil-1$, because the first is the number of vectors that need to be orthogonal in order to make the matrix "invalid". Sorry for my lack of concentration. To answer your question, we would get the number of matrices where for any vector at least $m/3$ of the row vectors are not orthogonal to that vector. I think this number is almost always 0. I can show you the code, if you want to do your own experiments.

Comment: @benh That would be great, thank you. I think Yury's view was that the probability is exponentially close to $1$ when you reduce the number of vectors you need to find to $m/3$ if I understood his comment below correctly.

Comment: @marshall Oh my! I should go to bed instead of spamming the comment section with half-baked thoughts... Of course is not $0$, as we have to check the rank of a $M+1-\lceil M/3 \rceil$-submatrix now (just substituting $2$ by $3$ looked tempting ;)) For $n=2$, $m \geq 2$ I get $8, 48, 224, 640, \dots $ which I can't find in OEIS.

Comment: @benh For $n=2, m \geq 2$ I get $8,48,96,640,3200,8960 \dots$ which also isn't in the OEIS. To be clear, I am checking the rank of every $(m+1-\lceil m/3 \rceil) $ by $n$ submatrix.  My  figures do not imply a probability that tends to $1$ however.  Can you reproduce them?

Comment: @user115998: It is easy to get an exact formula for $n=2$ (it's just a very easy generalization of the formula for your original problem). The number of possibilities is $2^m \sum_{k=\lceil m/3\rceil}^{\lfloor 2m/3\rfloor} \binom{m}{k}$ (check that your numbers agree with this formula!); the probability is $2^{-m} \sum_{k=\lceil m/3\rceil}^{\lfloor 2m/3\rfloor} \binom{m}{k}$. It tends to $1$ as $m\to+\infty$.

Comment: @Yury Your formula gives $8, 48, 96, 640, 3200, 8960, 46592, 215040$.  You are quite right the probability tends to $1$. It just does it non-monotonically which confused me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will give several bounds on the desired probability $p(m,n)$ and sketch their proofs.

**Note:** I assume that vectors in $X$ are counted with “repetitions/multiplicities”.

**Claim 1.** $p(m,n) \leq p(m, n-1)$.

*Proof:* Note that if $X$ satisfies the condition for given $m$ and $n$ then the restriction of vectors in $X$ to the first $n-1$ coordinates satisfies the condition for $m$ and $n' = n-1$. Thus $p(m,n) \leq p(m, n-1)$. It's not hard to see that the inequality is strict when $p(m,n-1) > 0$. *QED*

**Claim 2.** Suppose that $X$ satisfies the condition of the problem. Let $i$ and $j$ be distinct indices from $1$ to $n$. Then $$\sum_{u\in X} u_i u_j = 0$$ here, $u_i$ and $u_j$ are $i$-th and $j$-th coordinates of $u$, respectively.

*Proof:* Assume to the contrary that $\sum_{u\in X} u_i u_j \neq 0$ for some $i$ and $j$. Let us say that $\sum_{u\in X} u_i u_j > 0$. Note that $u_i u_j \in \{\pm 1\}$ for all $u\in \{\pm 1\}^n$. Let $Y$ be the set of vectors $u \in X$ with $u_i u_j = 1$; that is, $Y$ is the set of vector $u\in X$ such that either $u_i=u_j = 1$ or $u_i = u_j = -1$. Then $$0 < \sum_{u\in X} u_i u_j = |Y| - (|X| - |Y|) = 2|Y| -m$$ and thus $|Y| > m/2$.

Now consider $v=e_i - e_j$, where $e_i$ and $e_j$ are standard basis vectors. Note that $\langle v, u\rangle = 0$ for every $u\in Y$. Thus $v$ is orthogonal to more than $m/2$ vectors in $X$. We get a contradiction. The case when $\sum_{u\in X} u_i u_j < 0$ is similar: we consider $Y=\{u\in X: u_i u_j = -1\}$ and let $v=e_i + e_j$.

*QED*

**Remark.** Write an $n\times m$ matrix $U$ formed by vectors $u\in X$:
$$U = \left(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_m\right), \text{ where } X = \{x_1, \dots, x_m\},$$
Claim 2 says that if $X$ satisfies the condition of the problem then rows of $U$ are mutually orthogonal. Thus $p(m,n)$ is upper bounded by the probability that all rows of a random $n\times m$ matrix with $\pm 1$ entries are mutually orthogonal.

The product of each two rows has binomial distribution since it is the sum of $m$ independent $\pm 1$-Bernoulli random variables. Thus the probability that two rows are orthogonal is $\binom{m}{m/2}/2^m \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi\,m}}$ if $m$ is even and $0$ otherwise. We know that if $X$ satisfies the condition of the problem then *every* two rows are orthogonal. If the events for different pairs were independent, we would get an upper bound of 
$$\left(\binom{m}{m/2}/2^m\right)^{n(n-1)/2} \approx 1/m^{n(n-1)/4},$$ where $n(n-1)/2$ is the number of pairs of rows. But these events are not independent. So we use below a slightly different argument.

**Claim 3.** $$p(m,n) \leq C_n /m^{n(n-1)/4}$$ where $C_n$ depends only on $n$.

*Proof:* For $1 \leq i < j \leq n$, define $\xi_{ij}(u) = u_i u_j$. Then $\xi(u)$ is a random vector with $\binom{n}{2}$ coordinates. Consider vector $S = \sum_{u\in X} \xi(u)$. As we proved in Claim 2, if $X$ satisfies the condition then $S_{ij} = 0$ for every $1\leq i < j \leq n$; that is, vector $S$ equals $0$.

It is easy to see that the covariance matrix of $\xi$ is the identity matrix $I_{n(n-1)/2}$. Thus by the Central Limit Theorem $S$ is asymptotically distributed as $\cal{N}(0, m \, I_{n(n-1)/2})$ (multivariate normal distribution). Moreover, the Local Central Limit Theorem gives us a bound on the probability that $S=0$. Recall that the Local Central Limit Theorem shows that for every $S_0$,
$$\Pr(S=S_0) \leq C_n' \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi m}}\right)^{n(n-1)/2}\left(e^{-|S_0|^2/(2m)} + o(1)\right),$$
where $C_n'$ is a number that depends on $n$  (more precisely, on the distribution of $\xi$), $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi m}}\right)^{n(n-1)/2}\cdot e^{-|S_0|^2/(2m)}$ is the density of the multivariate distribution, and $o(1)$ is an error term.

Plugging $S_0 = 0$, we get that the probability is at most $C_n \cdot (1/\sqrt{m})^{n(n-1)/2} = C_n /m^{n(n-1)/4}$. Thus

$$p(m,n) \leq C_n /m^{n(n-1)/4}.$$

*QED*

**Claim 4.** We have:

1. $p(m,2) = \binom{m}{m/2}/2^m$ if $m$ is even;  $p(m,2) = 0$ if $m$ is odd.
2. $p(m,3) = m!/(4^m ((m/4)!)^4)$ if $m$ is divisive by 4;  $p(m,3) = 0$ otherwise.

*Proof:* Note that the condition on the set $X$ is equivalent to the following:

> **Condition $\star$:** Every hyperplane of dimension $n-1$ (passing through the origin) contains at most $n/2$ vectors from $X$.

Let us say that a hyperplane $H$ is maximal if there is no hyperplane $H'$ such that $H\cap \{\pm 1\}^n \subset H'\cap \{\pm 1\}^n$ and the inclusion is strict. It is clear that it suffices to consider only maximal hyperplanes in Condition $\star$. For $n=2$ the only maximal hyperplanes are 
$$H_1 = \{(u_1,u_2):u_1=u_2\} = \{(1,1),(-1,-1)\} \text{ and } H_2=\{(u_1,u_2):u_1=-u_2\}=\{(1,-1),(-1,1)\};$$
for $n=3$, every maximal hyperplane is of of the form 
$$H_{ij}^+ = \{(u_1,u_2,u_3):u_i=u_j\} \text{ and } H_{ij}^-=\{(u_1,u_2,u_3):u_i=-u_j\}$$

[image]

Let $f(v)$ be the number of vectors in $X$ (with multiplicities) equal to $v$ or $-v$. It is easy to check that $X$ satisfies Condition $\star$ if and only if $f(v) = m/2$ for every $v\in \{\pm 1 \}^2$ when $n=2$ and $f(v) = m/4$ for every $v\in \{\pm 1 \}^3$ when $n=3$. The statement of the claim follows.

*QED*

Comment: Is this argument very sensitive to the exact value $m/2$ in the question? Is it much the same for $m/10$ for example just with a few constants changed?

Comment: Thank you for this. Are there any prospects of a similar lower bound?

Comment: @marshall: the argument works for values up to $m/2 - \Theta(\sqrt{m})$. If the threshold is much smaller then that, the bound is not true; I think for such threshold the probability is exponentially close to $1$.

Comment: @user115998: for some $m$ the probability is just $0$; e.g., if $m$ is odd, it is $0$; if $m$ is not divisible by 4 and $n \geq 3$ the it is $0$. So any similar lower bound can be valid only for some values of $m$. There is probably a similar lower bound that works for some values of $m$.